# Facebook iOS SDK 'one-time' authorization

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to give users of my iPhone app the option to publish a story to their Facebook walls. Does this require that the user be presented with a sign on screen, and then a second screen authorizing the wall post or can these two screens be somehow combined into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign on screen will let user key in his credentials and thus allowing your application to access the information. You might like to read Extended Permissions for Facebook API for iphone.

You will need to open a dialog box right after he logs in to allow your application to access.modify content on his profile (like publishing a story). I am afraid If these two screens can be combined into one.

You can also refer to http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2

Comment: Thanks caprahul, That's the way I've currently implemented it. I thought I had remembered something about a one-time-authorization way of posting to a user's FB wall. This works fine though.